# Trying to find a FC-M371 crank on line but no luck for my part of the world (Australia, New Zealand, Pacific Islands)

Tags: crankset

I need a Shimano FC-M371 crank set for my 29 inch Avanti mountain bike. Crank arm 175mm, 44 teeth on large sprocket, 32 on medium, then 22 for small.

Having trouble location one in my part of the world. Is there an alternative compatible crankset that would fit that anyone knows about?  Or a reliable online supplier that I can get one shipped in from?  Thank you.

Comment: Put this into a google search   `Shimano FC-M371 site:nz`  and you can find useful results and some candidate suppliers.  There don't seem to be any sources on your loverly islands though sorry.

Comment: Another option for you is to try RAD  ("Recycle a dunger")  in Christchurch.  They have done a lot of support for the Islands and destinations in Africa too.   http://www.radbikes.co.nz/

Answer (score 1):

That is a standard square taper BB, so an square taper BB with suitable sized chain rings will replace it.  While 9 speed would be ideal, if the best chainring match you can find is 8speed it will work reasonably well.

As far as chain ring sizes, you do not need to stick with 44/32/22.  If you go larger than 44, you might need to lengthen the chain. If you increase the difference between the 44 and 22 (22), you may have problems getting it to work well.

A suitable low cost replacement might be FC-M311, which is commonly 22/32/42 - a slightly lower top gear.

Without offering recommendations, Wiggle and Chain Reaction in the UK happily supply into NZ (as long as its not Shimano) , along with JensonUSA in the US. You LBS will be able to source a suitable replacement very easily, and unless you have access to a crank puller, probably cheaper to get them to install it.

Comment: You're right - wiggle and CRC and those "overseas" suppliers won't ship to New Zealand any more due to  Shimano cracking down.  Someone has bought the wholesale contract for a region, they don't appreciate users getting the part from Wiggle at less than the wholesale cost.

Comment: For the stuff the ship to NZ, they use geopricing as well - look up and item, then use a VPN to connect to the UK and look up the same item. The USA is honest about pricing, they charge the same to anyone, but they have high freight costs. Best option is often to use a VPN and via to a UK based proxy.

Answer (score 1):

There are in the latest Shimano catalogue these 44-32-22 cranks:

- FC-M371 - square taper, riveted chainrings, 9-speed
- FC-MT101 - ditto
- FC-MT210-3, riveted, HT2 9-speed
- FC-T4060 - removable chainrings, HT2 9-speed
- FC-T4010 - removable, Octalink 9-sped
- FC-T3010 - square taper, removable chainrings, 9-speed

In general, you might well want to replace your BB, and if you're doing so the best option would probably be to go HT2, in that square taper is fine but Shimano are making progressively lower quality (cheaper) square taper BBs, and quality third party BBs will be expensive. Octalink is dead and will be combined to the trash can of history soon enough, so ignore that as you don't already have it.

It's very cheap and easy to remove your crankset, a crank puller is like $3 from China.

https://www.aliexpress.com/item/4000004797608.html

or $5 for a slightly fancier one with a handle

https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005001375554955.html

Unfortunately removing the bottom bracket can be more challenging and you will want to buy a branded tool. However if your bottom bracket does need replacement then it's not significantly more expensive to replace it with a HT2 model.

This is the tool to remove an Octalink or Square Taper BB

[image]

Whereas a cheap $5 tool like this will do for HT2

https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32988218792.html